# Getting error while doing subprocess call using Python and Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting some error while running the `.sh` script using Python and Django. The errors are given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cell.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.call(shlex.split('./test.sh param1 param2'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I am explaining my code below.

> cell.py:

```
  import subprocess
import shlex
param1='Reactor1'
param2='Running'
subprocess.call(shlex.split('bash test.sh',param1,param2))
```

> test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
echo $2
exit 0
```

While I was running the file I am getting the above error. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Does `test.sh` have the `+x` attribute set?

Comment: I just created the file and saved inside the same project folder.

Comment: go check it then... alternatively try `bash test.sh param1 param2`

Comment: instead of `./test.sh param1 param2` right ?

Comment: @NilsWerner : Ok I did as per you and also error gone but the echo message is not coming.

Comment: Your code now no longer fits to your error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('bash test.sh',param1,param2))
```

To

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('bash test1.sh %s %s'%(param1,param2)))
```

or

```
subprocess.call(['bash', 'test1.sh', param1, param2])
```

Comment: @subhra  you are passing parameter but not formatted correctly, that was the error

Comment: why create a string only to split it again later? Just use `subprocess.call(['bash', 'test1.sh', param1, param2])` instead